# Good Database Solutions for small-medium Traffic Sites and Silverlight

Tags: database, silverlight-4.0, web

What are some good database solutions that support Silverlight and are solid for a small-medium traffic website

Easy to use/Manage is a very strong plus

edit: Forgot to mention that the database needs to be very smartphone-friendly, it needs to be able to work with devices on iOS, Android, and Windows Phone 7

Comment: Sorry, Smartphones and Silverlight? That doesn't fit.

Comment: Silverlight itself no, well not for most at least (supposedly coming to WP7 next fall) but a database that supports those environments I'm sure exists

Comment: Can you explain the relation between the Smartphone and the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you term small-medium. I would say SQL Server Express should suit your needs.

It is free, but your database size cannot be more than 10 GB. It also limits the resources that can be used from the server.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/Default.aspx

Comment: Users would be most likely added in around increments of 20-100 and the Network Effect would be very influential.

Comment: If you outgrow express, you can move up to the full version.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight is not bound to a database.
Every database available to ADO.NET is usable within .NET.
MSSQL Express is a good solution (especially in .NET env) as well as any other like MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Express is a pretty obvious choice. Integrates very well, tons of first class documentation, very reliable, good management studio, upgradeable to more powerful versions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your edit, it appears to be a windows phone 7 app that you're going to make, and that you want the database stored on the phone (as opposed to connecting to an internet based datasource). In that case, you might want to take a look at [SQL Server 2008 Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx).

Scott Hanselman has an article about using EF Code First with SQL Server Compact (His solution does not specifically include Silverlight, but it works just the same iirc) [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimpleCodeFirstWithEntityFramework4MagicUnicornFeatureCTP4.aspx).

Comment: It wouldn't be just limited to Windows Phone 7.

Comment: @Indebi: You might have difficulties using Silverlight on a non-windows phone. I'm not sure what the support for it is in Mono.